# Migrations from modules are not executed by yiic migrate command

Tags: php, yii, migration

I am trying to install a user module in my Yii-based application. To do this, I have to migrate the files from:

```
webapp/protected/modules/user/migrations
```

I trying to run `yiic migrate --migrationPath=user.migrations`, but I'm getting an error:

```
the migration directory does not exist: user.migrations
```

I read that I have to set up user.migrations as an alias but I don't know how to do it.

I also read, that migration's default folder is determined by`basePath` value, set in main configuration file (`protected/config/main.php`). I have changed it and it still  doesn't work correctly.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

`yiic migrate --migrationPath=application.modules.user.migrations`

Answer (score 4):

from your Command Line open the yiic of your **protected folder**. Not the yiic of the **framework folder**.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone cant seem to make it work, here are some details:

Use: *./yiic migrate --migrationPath=application.dirName.migrations*

How come?
Check the class **MigrateCommand**.
The public property *$migrationPath='application.migrations'* where *'application'* will become *'/home/yourUser/yourYiiApp/protected/* and *'migrations'* will become, well *'migrations'* after gets parsed.
So if you are running *./yiic* just point to *dirname/migrationFolder*

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else is struggling with this, I had to go into the protected folder and force it to use the right yiic with:

`php yiic.php migrate --migrationPath=application.modules.user.migrations`